# Specifying list of arguments with minimum one argument in list

Tags: python, function, arguments, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

So, I have some function that takes a list of arguments with minimum one argument, but potentially an entire list of arguments. I know a couple ways of defining this method, but I'm trying to determine what the various alternatives are at my disposal and what the various advantages of each approach are.

I'm trying to figure out what possible prototypes I can use to define this argument. I've considered the following:

```
def func(arg_1, *args):
    arg_list = (arg_1,) + args
    # do stuff with arg_list
```

as well as

```
def func(*args):
    if len(args) == 0: raise Exception("Not enough arguments specified")
    # do stuff with args
```

Are there alternative ways to specify a function that takes an argument list with minimum one argument?

Comment: There is also `assert len(args) > 0` that will throw an `AssertionError`

Comment: Ah, yes. Definitely another viable alternative.

Comment: `if not args` is more idiomatic than explicitly checking its length.

Answer (score 1):

In **[Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)** you can (it has been present since `3.0` I believe, when **[`PEP 3102`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/)** came out) but with the restrictions that *the extra arguments are defined without a default value* **and** *supplied in a keyword form when calling the defined function*.

This is done by adding `*` as a separator and the required argument(s) after it:

```
def foo(*, must_specify, **kwargs): pass
```

Calling `foo()` without supplying the a keyword argument of the form `must_specify = 'specified'` will result in a `TypeError` hinting the requirement for that specific argument:

```
foo()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-624891b0d01a> in <module>()
----> 1 foo()

TypeError: foo() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'must_specify'
```

Positional arguments on their own can be supplied, but, the positional grouping parameter of the form `*args` cannot i.e:

```
def foo(pos_arg, *, must_specify, **kwargs): pass
```

is fine, but:

```
def foo(pos_arg, *args, *, must_specify, **kwargs): pass
```

is a `SyntaxError`. This is done because `*` is essentially the same as a 'throw-away' form of `*args`.

Either way, there is no other *syntactic* way (that I'm aware of) which can satisfy the restriction you wish. If working with `kwargs` is too much of a hassle for you or if you're working with `Py2` and are adamant to switch, solutions as those suggested in the comments are your best bet.